Can React props be used in CSS?
I have a display: grid;, set to the body of my react-app.
I have a component that uses a part of the grid that I want to repeat itself two more times side by side.
How do I used props for the CSS property, grid-area: , so I can change the position of other two within the grid, slightly modifying the reusable component?
I tried using props the usual way but this only affects the html and am confused on how to change a css property for a reusable component.
Here is the code:
function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <Sidebar />
      <Main />
      <Content h1="Content1"/>
      
      <Footer/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

import './Content.css'

function Content(props) {
    return (
        <div className="content">
            <h1>{props.h1}</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                Nemo laborum sapiente placeat dolorem a quae!
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Content

.content {
    grid-area: content1;
}
.content h1 {
    padding: 1rem;
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0 0;
}
.content p {
    padding: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

The layout is working as expected,
I just want to change the CSS property grid-area:  to a newer position.
Do you know the syntax for modifying a specific CSS property when styling with react props?

The main way is to use a css-in-js library like Styled Components.

You can define multiple CSS classes, e.g. .content, .content-special and apply the one you need from React. Or define nested CSS classes, e.g. .content, .content.special and apply the one(s) you need from React.

You can use the style attribute to set css custom properties on your element and pass values from JavaScript/React to CSS.
function Content(props) {
    const gridLayout = props.gridLayout ?? 'content1';
    return (
        <div
            className="content"
            style={{ '--my-var': gridLayout } as React.CSSProperties}
        >
            <h1>{props.h1}</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                Nemo laborum sapiente placeat dolorem a quae!
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

Then in CSS you can reference the variable that was passed in via the style attribute:
.content {
  grid-area: var(--my-var);
}

(see this question for why the as React.CSSProperties assertion is needed)

You can also just pass the CSS property itself without using a custom property, e.g. style={{ gridArea: gridLayout }}.

This solved my problem. Thank you.
